# Access Database - Display different data

Tags: database, visual-studio, ms-access, datagridview

Good morning everybody, this is the first time I write in this forum so, i'm sorry if I do some error!!!

I'm working on a project in Visual Studio where I'm connecting to an Access Database. The most important thing is that this Database is not mine and I can't modify it because it is updated daily by another automatic software.
I have to think that this database is "Read Only".
This database only has tables with primary key but there are no relation between tables.....it really looks like different Excel sheets!!!

I don't have problem to import the tables in a DatagridView of my Visual Studio project but in these tables the data are not easy to be understood for example:

- there is a column named "Color" where the color are filled like number but there is not another Table who contain the color code. I know in my mind that color 1=Red, 2=Orange, 3=Brown etc.....

What I want to do?

I want that in my DataGridView won't be show the numbers but the color name so I need to modify my DataGrid source before display data.

How is did my project?

I have my DatagridView whose data source is a BindingSource that has a Dataset as DataSource. On my Load event I use the "Fill" method of my TableAdapter to display my tables data

Could someone suggest me how modify data before display them?

Thanks a lot

Giacomo

Answer (score 0):

If all you are dealing with is a limited number of values in one or two fields, you could select the records using a query and obtain the color as follows:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.FldA, Table1.ClrFlag,  IIf([clrflag]=1,"RED",IIf([clrflag]=2,"Orange",IIf([clrflag]=3,"Brown","Unknown"))) 
AS MyClr
FROM Table1
```

If there are many lookup's to do, I would create my own database with tables of code translations and join the two databases to produce my result. The following is an example of SQL pulling from two databases:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/113701/how-to-access-multiple-databases-in-an-sql-query-in-vb-3-0